# MySQL - Interact between Query and Subquery, it is possible?

Tags: mysql

Let's assume this complex query;

```
SELECT cl.id, cl.nombre, 
    (SELECT count(*) FROM (SELECT count(ac.id)
    FROM acciones ac
    LEFT JOIN inter_clientes_acciones ia ON ac.id = ia.id_accion
    LEFT JOIN clientes cl ON ia.id_cliente = cl.id
    WHERE fecha_fin < CURDATE() AND ac.id_proyecto = 3 AND id_cliente = 3
    GROUP BY ac.id
    HAVING count(*) > 1) tabla_ac_grupales) as ac_grupales,
    (SELECT count(*) FROM (SELECT count(ac.id)
    FROM acciones ac
    LEFT JOIN inter_clientes_acciones ia ON ac.id = ia.id_accion
    LEFT JOIN clientes cl ON ia.id_cliente = cl.id
    WHERE fecha_fin < CURDATE() AND ac.id_proyecto = 3 AND id_cliente = 3
    GROUP BY ac.id
    HAVING count(*) = 1) tabla_ac_individuales ) as ac_individuales
FROM inter_clientes_acciones ia
JOIN clientes cl ON ia.id_cliente = cl.id
JOIN acciones ac ON ia.id_accion = ac.id
WHERE cl.id = 3 AND asistencia = 1 AND (ia.id_accion IN (
    SELECT ac.id as id_accion
    FROM acciones ac
    LEFT JOIN inter_clientes_acciones ia ON ac.id = ia.id_accion
    LEFT JOIN clientes cl ON ia.id_cliente = cl.id
    WHERE fecha_fin < CURDATE() AND ac.id_proyecto = 3
    GROUP BY ac.id
    HAVING count(*) > 1
 ) OR ia.id_accion IN (
    SELECT ac.id as id_accion
    FROM acciones ac
    LEFT JOIN inter_clientes_acciones ia ON ac.id = ia.id_accion
    LEFT JOIN clientes cl ON ia.id_cliente = cl.id
    WHERE fecha_fin < CURDATE() AND ac.id_proyecto = 3
    GROUP BY ac.id
    HAVING count(*) = 1  
 )
)
GROUP BY cl.id
```

As you can see, we have 2 subqueries that count the number of rows of another subqueries and returns all the clients that match the where clauses (in which we have another subqueries) plus the number of actions attended by this client. The fact is that I have marked `cl.id = 3` in the where clauses of the query and the subqueries. My question is, how can I do the query and the subqueries without specifying the client id? What I want is to obtain all the client with his numbers.

Can this be done with a query or I have to do an stored procedure? Also if you know a better way to do this feel free to say it.

**Schema Actions:**

```
id
(another non important fields)
```

**Schema Clients:**

```
id
(another non important fields)
```

**Schema inter_clients_actions:**

```
id
id_client
id_action
attend (Boolean)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't this

```
WHERE cl.id = 3 AND asistencia = 1 AND (ia.id_accion IN (
    SELECT ac.id as id_accion
    FROM acciones ac
    LEFT JOIN inter_clientes_acciones ia ON ac.id = ia.id_accion
    LEFT JOIN clientes cl ON ia.id_cliente = cl.id
    WHERE fecha_fin < CURDATE() AND ac.id_proyecto = 3
    GROUP BY ac.id
    HAVING count(*) > 1
 ) OR ia.id_accion IN (
    SELECT ac.id as id_accion
    FROM acciones ac
    LEFT JOIN inter_clientes_acciones ia ON ac.id = ia.id_accion
    LEFT JOIN clientes cl ON ia.id_cliente = cl.id
    WHERE fecha_fin < CURDATE() AND ac.id_proyecto = 3
    GROUP BY ac.id
    HAVING count(*) = 1  
 )
)
```

be simply just:

```
WHERE cl.id = 3 AND asistencia = 1 AND (ia.id_accion IN (
    SELECT ac.id as id_accion
    FROM acciones ac
    LEFT JOIN inter_clientes_acciones ia ON ac.id = ia.id_accion
    LEFT JOIN clientes cl ON ia.id_cliente = cl.id
    WHERE fecha_fin < CURDATE() AND ac.id_proyecto = 3
    GROUP BY ac.id
    HAVING count(*) >= 1
 )
)
```

And also very simply:

```
AND id_cliente = 3
```

Be

```
AND id_cliente = cl.id
```

The final query:

```
SELECT cl.id, cl.nombre, 
    (SELECT count(*) FROM (SELECT count(ac.id)
    FROM acciones ac
    LEFT JOIN inter_clientes_acciones ia ON ac.id = ia.id_accion
    LEFT JOIN clientes cl ON ia.id_cliente = cl.id
    WHERE fecha_fin < CURDATE() AND ac.id_proyecto = 3 AND id_cliente = cl.id
    GROUP BY ac.id
    HAVING count(*) >= 1) tabla_ac_grupales) as res_all
FROM inter_clientes_acciones ia
JOIN clientes cl ON ia.id_cliente = cl.id
JOIN acciones ac ON ia.id_accion = ac.id
WHERE asistencia = 1 AND (ia.id_accion IN (
    SELECT ac.id as id_accion
    FROM acciones ac
    LEFT JOIN inter_clientes_acciones ia ON ac.id = ia.id_accion
    LEFT JOIN clientes cl ON ia.id_cliente = cl.id
    WHERE fecha_fin < CURDATE() AND ac.id_proyecto = cl.id
    GROUP BY ac.id
    HAVING count(*) >= 1
 )
)
GROUP BY cl.id
```

And when `res_all > 1` then groups, when `res_all = 1' then individual.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, with `cl.id`inside subquery solves all my troubles. Is there a way to add a where clause using res_all? like where `res_all < 2`. Again thanks for your help @Kilanny

Comment: Put your hole query as a subquery `SELECT * FROM (....) as tmp WHERE res_all < 2`

Comment: You are a SQL god! I owe you my life! Thanks @Kilanny

Comment: There is no God but Allah, The Beneficent The Merciful